# More than one master page for share point 2013 same public site?

Tags: 2013, master-page, custom-masterpage, multiple-values

Is it possible to have more than one master page in share point 2013 for same site? I was able to create two master page in Design Manager and two different layout for the two different master pages. But When I am creating a page it always takes the default master page even though when I am assigning the other layout which has different master page linked to it.

Like most of the time a website has different design for home page and inner page. I can't figured it out how to have two different master page for home page and inner pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Device Channels to specify separate master pages based on the User Agent of the browser viewing the site.

That's the only mechanism for using different sets of master pages.

Comment: but that for different device. I mean for mobile device, Pad's, PC etc. But I want to have two master page for two different page not channel. That's not possible?

Comment: Unfortunately no.  You can set two master pages: the site (used for content pages) and the system (used for admin pages).  You can't specify different master pages for different pages in the same site.

Comment: thanks. Ya seems like that. I can't change it. Although you can change it in Pages/YourPage.aspx file but that won't work too ... :(

Comment: You can hard code the Master Page path into the Page Layout. e.g. if you know that a custom page layout always needs to use a specific Master Page then hardcode the path to that master page at the top of the page layout. e.g.: 
<%@ Page masterpagefile="custom2.master"