# How to create left side custom navigation as common?

Tags: sharepoint-online, html, boot-strap

I have created the custom left navigation in HTML with bootstrap. I need to add this in SharePoint online team site. If I include this HTML in SharePoint Online, I want to use wherever I want in the team site pages. But I must import only once this HTML template. Is this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: This question is very open ended. If you can provide details of what you have tried till now and where you are stuck, then you will get better response.

Comment: Actually we have created the HTML pages and import it in sharepoint site. but the left navigation is common for some pages. So i need to add it common. I can able to add the navigation with page contents for all pages. But i need to add navigation once in that site and make use of it.

Answer (score 0):

You can add it in the Master Page level or in the page Layout corresponding to your Page

Comment: we can have only one master for site. 
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/83044/more-than-one-master-page-for-share-point-2013-same-public-site
can we able to edit the page layouts?